# Issue with updating a property that is an array nested inside another array in redux state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, state

So I've been browsing through the issues regarding redux state on here and can't seem to find one that helps me. My issue is that I have state that looks like this:

```
state = {
  products = [
    {
      name: "Example",
      description: "Example",
      images: ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg'],
      imgNum: 2,
    }
  ]
}
```

And I would like to add to images and imgNum like this:

```
state = {
  products = [
    {
      name: "Example",
      description: "Example",
      images: ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg'],
      imgNum: 3,
    }
  ]
}
```

(This is an example, the actual code has more properties and items but images and imgNum are the items of concern)
So when I try to update the images array or imgNum I am unable to. Here is what the case looks like:

```
case ADD_IMAGE:
  return {
    ...state,
    products: state.products.map((item, i) => {
      if(item.name === payload.name) {
        return {
          ...item,
          images: [...item.images, payload.image],
          imgNum: item.imgNum + 1,
        }
      }
      return item;
    });
  }
```

I've checked to make sure that in that scope item.images, ...item.images, and item.imgNum are all defined and they all return values when console.log'ed before the return in the if statement. I've also tried different values in place of ...item.images but the only other one that doesn't throw an undefined error is

```
...state.products[i].images
```

and it also didn't result in any state changes.

Just a clarification - with my code as it is now I don't get any errors, but the state also is not updated.

payload.name and payload.image also return values and not undefined, as per the ol console.log test again.

Another thing I tried was declaring variables outside of the return statement and then using them inside like this:

```
case ADD_IMAGE:
  return {
    ...state,
    products: state.products.map((item, i) => {
      if(item.name === payload.name) {
        const newArr = [...item.images, payload.image];
        const newNum = item.imgNum +1;
        return {
          ...item,
          images: newArr,
          imgNum: newNum
        }
      }
      return item;
    });
  }
```

But this brilliant bit of coding resulted in nothing.

Any help is appreciated, I'm sure I've overlooked (or completely blown by) some nuance of updating state. 
Let me know if additional info is needed! Thanks in advance all.

Edit to show action:

```
export const uploadImage = (data, image, item) => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .post("/products/upload-image", data)
    .then(() => {
      dispatch({type: ADD_IMAGE, payload: {image: image, name: item.name}})
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

So this is the action I use, and it is called on a file upload event. I know it works because the image is uploaded to my db (the axios part), and because redux-logger shows the ADD_IMAGE action occurring on file upload. The payload image and name are as expected, so that stuff is all working.

Comment: You don't even need to store the number of images, because you can always use images.length to get that number.

Comment: The code you've provided looks fine, Can you check the store state in redux dev tools or using `getState` on the store if it is being updated ?

Comment: This is true, I had set up imgNum at beginning of project and glossed over it as things progressed. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Hemant I'm using redux-logger to show me real time what is occuring with the state, and can see in both that and redux dev tools that the state is not being updated

Comment: Can you check if you're dispatching the right ACTION or maybe provide additional code? with this much we can't tell much. Providing a minimal example demonstrating the issue will help.

Comment: @Hemant I added an edit above showing the action I'm calling. It is definitely dispatching as redux-logger shows it dispatching and my db receives an upload for that bit. What else should I provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those that put forward suggestions. I came up with a workaround I'll stick here.

Instead of fiddling around with the reducer stuff anymore, I changed what I was sending when the action fired. I handled getting the current image array from the store, storing it as a new variable, pushing my new image onto that new variable array, and then providing the new variable to my action, which updates the image array as a whole. Here are some snippets in case that isn't super clear:

```
    case ADD_IMAGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        products: state.products.map((item) => {
          if (item.name === payload.name) {
            return {
              ...item,
              images: payload.imageArr
            };
          }
          return item;
        }),
      };
```

note that image just is assigned payload.imageArr now.

In my component, I did this:

```
    const imageName = `${Math.round(Math.random() * 100000000).toString()}.jpg`;
    const oldArr = currentItem.images;
    oldArr.push(imageName);
```

where currentItem is an object in my store that is set by an event handler earlier on, and has all the same props as any other product in the products array. imageName is just that random string that I assign the image, and then I just push it onto the array. Then that 'oldArr' (excuse the lame naming, but wanted it to be clear) is passed when the action is called, and assigned as payload.imageArr as mentioned above.

Thanks Red Baron, Hemant, and Ceva Comic for your input on the issue!

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
    products: state.products.map((item, i) => {
      if(item.name === payload.name) {
        const newArr = [...item.images, payload.image];
        const newNum = item.imgNum +1;
        return {
          ...item,
          images: newArr,
          imgNum: newNum
        }
      }
      return item;
    });
```

try this:

```
  return {
    ...state,
    products: state.products.map((item, i) => 
      item.name === payload.name ? {
          ...item,
          images: item.images.concat(payload.image),
          imgNum: item.imgNum +1
      } : item,
    )
  }
```

Comment: ```...state.products.images``` won't return what I want as the images array is stored inside of the individual item, which is in the products array. ```...state.products.item.images``` would be closer, but also returns undefined.

Comment: @Tim ah yeh ok. are you sure you've a) action deffo being called? b) console.log to show it's getting in the reducer with the right stuff? c) when you say state isn't getting updated, is that because the view isn't or because the redux dev tools aren't showing it (or both)

Comment: I added an edit to the post showing the action I'm calling. I'm sure it is being called as redux-logger shows it being called, and my upload works. RE c) both are not updating - the state is not updating in redux dev tools, and therefore the view is also not updating.

Comment: and just to confirm @Tim, is the case statement being triggered?

Comment: Yes it is, everything is being triggered alright, I just seem to have trouble accessing the item.images value inside of that return statement (also I'm unable to tag your name, sorry!)

Comment: can you show where `uploadImage` is called OR better, can you confirm when it's called, the `uploadImage = (data, image, item) ` are correct?

Comment: I think you were overwriting `item` every time by that final `return` statement

Comment: Yes it is correct - data is right as my image is successfully uploaded to my database, image is correct as a console.log(image) when the action is called results in the string I expected, and item is correct as a console.log(item.name) when the action is called results in the string I expected.

Comment: Oh okay I like that I'll give that a try (re new answer)

Comment: that didn't appear to work, seems to be the same as previous code

Comment: hmm, very odd. you sure this is matching? `item.name === payload.name`

Comment: Yes it is, just confirmed with a bunch of tests ahah

Comment: Ok mate. I’ll keep digging. This is baffling me haha

Comment: Thanks! haha I'm confused too, the code seems right.